# How can I avoid a KeyNotFoundException in DataView.ToTable()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataview

I am working on a legacy ASP.NET code base that has *some* information stored in cache (via Enterprise Library) inside `DataTable` objects. It is a multiple user, intranet  environment, running in .NET 4.0. An issue exists in production that points back to a prior "fixed" issue as its probable root cause: a `KeyNotFoundException` that occurs in an invocation of `DataView.ToTable()`. This particular code is part of validation that can occur during the loading of a page from the majority of pages in the application.

```
var table = GetSomeDataTableFromCache();
var view = table.DefaultView;
view.RowFilter = "Foo = 'Bar'";
var filteredTable = view.ToTable();
```

This is the simplification of the code. What has happened is that in days *long* since passed, this code was apparently throwing the aforementioned exception. A prior developer "fixed" it by catching and swallowing the exception and returning null. This behavior is the presumed culprit in other issues that have come to light.

I have attempted to reproduce the original exception without much success. I feel that if I can reproduce it, I can understand it and attempt to form a solution to the original problem that is better than *ignoring it*, and thereby also avoid the mess that *ignoring it* has created.

I note that Google searches on `DataView.ToTable() + KeyNotFoundException` produced results suggesting validating that the column name exists. An example is located here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1695676.aspx/1

However, I have observed that when setting the `RowFilter` to an invalid column name, an `EvaluateException` occurs on that line. I have also attempted to troubleshoot the error by using an empty table, and also by using a filter that produces an empty result. Each scenario proves non-exceptional.

So where would a `KeyNotFoundException` occur, if it is not an invalid column name as suggested? And once we know how it occurs, how can we avoid it?

Comment: Note: This question is self-answered based on an actual production issue and the research conducted. Due to similar (yet non-helpful) questions existing on the internet for this particular code and exception, I've posted it and do not *think* it is too localized to my current situation. However, I am certainly interested in additional answers, as I am by no means an expert on DataViews and threading and considerations thereof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that ASP.NET is inherently a multithreaded system. [`DataView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) is documented to be thread-safe for reads, but not for writes. This is important to consider.

In the snippet presented, pulling an instance of a `DataTable` from cache and accessing its `DefaultView` for filtering and writing to a new `DataTable` is going to potentially present a condition that would prove unsafe, and it is not because of the columns in the filter, but rather the multiple threads that could be executing the same code at the same time.

As an implementation detail, `DataView` utilizes several bits of internal state. During the `ToTable()` execution, there are multiple pieces of non-local state involved. In particular, there is a dictionary field that is keyed on DataRow, and also a DataRow field that is used as the key! This dictionary gets cleared, added to, the row gets overwritten with a value referencing a row and then is set to null and this is all part of the process. When multiple threads are executing this at the same time, it is not inconceivable that one thread is overwriting and invalidating the state that another thread is depending on. This can lead to the exception as noted in the question, as well as other potentially harmful consequences.

At any rate, let's try to reproduce the issue using the code snippet as a starting point, also in an environment that can take advantage of multiple executions.

```
static void Main()
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Foo");
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(i.ToString(), i);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) 
    {
        Enumerable
           .Range(0,100)
           .AsParallel()
           .ForAll(item => ExecuteToTable(table, item));
    }
}

static void ExecuteToTable(DataTable table, int item)
{
    var view = table.DefaultView;
    view.RowFilter = string.Format("Foo = '{0}'", item);
    var filteredTable = view.ToTable();
}
```

Does this generate the exception? Run it to see! It may require multiple executions, but if the machine running the code is any similar to mine, it will not take many. (With the loop over the parallel query, it really just takes once for me.)

I have run this code in LinqPad and the "desired" exception has been generated. Since this is a parallel query execution, it will be wrapped in an AggregatedException, but the InnerException will tell the tale.

> KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

```
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at System.Data.DataView.CopyTo(DataRowView[] array, Int32 index)
at System.Data.DataView.GetEnumerator()
at System.Data.DataView.ToTable(String tableName, Boolean distinct, String[] columnNames)
at System.Data.DataView.ToTable()
```

So we've reproduced it, and hopefully understood it. How about avoiding it? There are several possible solutions, some more palatable than others depending upon your use case, which can range from a wholesale rewrite to just subtle changes.

**You can**

**Copy the DataTable** using `table.Copy()` **prior** to accessing the DefaultView. This will give each request its own table (in the above snippet). However, if the table is large, copying could prove expensive. Try to run the above reproduction code using `Copy()` and  see if the exception is avoided.

**Avoid the DataView entirely**. Linq is useful against DataTables, as well. The below snippet can be used to produce a filtered DataTable output. However, also note that `CopyToDataTable()` could throw its *own* exception if no rows pass the filter. If there is a chance of that happening, split the code and check for results (with .Any()) prior to invoking the last portion. Another drawback versus the `DataView` is that using a `DataView` allows you to specify which columns you wish to include in the output table if you utilize the available `ToTable` overload.

```
var filteredTable
        = table.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(row => string.Equals(row.Field<string>("Foo"), item.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
               .CopyToDataTable();
```

And of course you can explore redesigning the code further, adding your own measures for thread safety to the caching strategy, etc., although these would take more time to implement that changing the way the actual table is filtered.